# How do I implement a Bézier curve in C++?

Tags: c++, math, interpolation, spline

I'd like to implement a [Bézier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).  How should I go about creating a quadratic curve?

```
void printQuadCurve(float delta, Vector2f p0, Vector2f p1, Vector2f p2);
```

Clearly we'd need to use linear interpolation, but does this exist in the standard math library? If not, where can I find it?

I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Recently I ran across the same question and wanted to implemented it on my own.
This image from Wikipedia helped me:

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Bezier_quadratic_anim.gif]

The following code shows how to compute a quadratic bezier.

```
int interpolate( int from , int to , float percent )
{
    int difference = to - from;
    return from + ( difference * percent );
}    

for( float i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i += 0.01 )
{
    // The Green Line
    xa = interpolate( x1 , x2 , i );
    ya = interpolate( y1 , y2 , i );
    xb = interpolate( x2 , x3 , i );
    yb = interpolate( y2 , y3 , i );

    // The Black Dot
    x = interpolate( xa , xb , i );
    y = interpolate( ya , yb , i );
    
    drawPixel( x , y , COLOR_RED );
}
```

With (x1|y1), (x2|y2) and (x3|y3) being P0, P1 and P2 in the image. Just for showing the basic idea...

For the ones who ask for the cubic bezier, it just works analogue (also from Wikipedia):

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Bezier_cubic_anim.gif]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642168/how-to-convert-quadratic-bezier-curve-code-into-cubic-bezier-curve/37642695#37642695) answer provides Code for it.

Comment: Great Reply, but this technically a DeCasteljau representation.  Which is easier to understand, but usually less optimal.

Comment: Thanks! You're totally right. What I needed at the time was a vivid understanding of berzier curves (that people feel a similar desire is probably the reason this answer was upvoted that many times). Most other algorithms are (often necessary) optimizations of the DeCasteljau, so it seems to be a really good foundation upon which knowledge can easily build upon.

Comment: @EnderDoe DeCasteljau method is numerically stable.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a general implementation for a curve with any number of points.

```
vec2 getBezierPoint( vec2* points, int numPoints, float t ) {
    vec2* tmp = new vec2[numPoints];
    memcpy(tmp, points, numPoints * sizeof(vec2));
    int i = numPoints - 1;
    while (i > 0) {
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
            tmp[k] = tmp[k] + t * ( tmp[k+1] - tmp[k] );
        i--;
    }
    vec2 answer = tmp[0];
    delete[] tmp;
    return answer;
}
```

Note that it uses heap memory for a temporary array which is not all that efficient. If you only need to deal with a fixed number of points you could hard-code the numPoints value and use stack memory instead.

Of course, the above assumes you have a vec2 structure and operators for it like this:

```
struct vec2 {
    float x, y;
    vec2(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

vec2 operator + (vec2 a, vec2 b) {
    return vec2(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
}

vec2 operator - (vec2 a, vec2 b) {
    return vec2(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y);
}

vec2 operator * (float s, vec2 a) {
    return vec2(s * a.x, s * a.y);
}
```

Comment: @ifroce2d which type of curve is that?

Comment: ?? It's bezier as per the question and the function name "getBezierPoint"

Comment: @ifroce2d The basic Idea shall be the same for Vector3 right ?

Answer (score 14):

You have a choice between de Casteljau's method, which is to recursively split the control path until you arrive at the point using a linear interpolation, as explained above, or Bezier's method which is to blend the control points.

Bezier's method is

```
 p = (1-t)^3 *P0 + 3*t*(1-t)^2*P1 + 3*t^2*(1-t)*P2 + t^3*P3
```

for cubics and

```
 p = (1-t)^2 *P0 + 2*(1-t)*t*P1 + t*t*P2
```

for quadratics.

t is usually on 0-1 but that's not an essential - in fact the curves extend to infinity. P0, P1, etc are the control points. The curve goes through the two end points but not usually through the other points.

Answer (score 7):

Did you use a C# library earlier?

In C++, no standard library function for Bezier curves is available (yet). You can of course roll your own (CodeProject [sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/BezirCurves.aspx)) or look for a math library.

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304095548/http://blog.paultondeur.com/2008/03/09/drawing-a-cubic-bezier-curve-using-actionscript-3/) blogpost explains the idea nicely but in Actionscript. Translation should not be much of a problem.

Comment: Just an FYI. The link to the blog post shows an empty page.

Comment: @RSahu Thanks for flagging; I found an archived copy in Wayback Machine and edited the answer.

Answer (score 4):

To get an individual point `(x, y)` along a cubic curve at a given percent of travel `(t)`, with given control points `(x1, y1)`, `(x2, y2)`, `(x3, y3)`, and `(x4, y4)` I expanded De Casteljau’s algorithm and rearranged the equation to minimize exponents:

```
//Generalized code, not C++
variables passed to function:   t,  x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4
variables declared in function: t2, t3, x,  y
t2 = t * t
t3 = t * t * t
x = t3*x4 + (3*t2 - 3*t3)*x3 + (3*t3 - 6*t2 + 3*t)*x2 + (3*t2 - t3 - 3*t + 1)*x1
y = t3*y4 + (3*t2 - 3*t3)*y3 + (3*t3 - 6*t2 + 3*t)*y2 + (3*t2 - t3 - 3*t + 1)*y1
```

`(t)` is a decimal value  between 0 and 1 `(0 <= t <= 1)` that represents percent of travel along the curve.

The formula is the same for x and y, and you can write a function that takes a generic set of 4 control points or group the coefficients together:

```
t2 = t * t
t3 = t * t * t

A = (3*t2 - 3*t3)
B = (3*t3 - 6*t2 + 3*t)
C = (3*t2 - t3 - 3*t + 1)

x = t3*x4 + A*x3 + B*x2 + C*x1
y = t3*y4 + A*y3 + B*y2 + C*y1
```

For quadratic functions, a similar approach yields:

```
t2 = t * t

A = (2*t - 2*t2)
B = (t2 - 2*t + 1)

x = t2*x3 + A*x2 + B*x1
y = t2*y3 + A*y2 + B*y1
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you just want to display a Bezier curve, you can use something like [PolyBezier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162811.aspx) for Windows.
- If you want to implement the routine yourself, you can find [linear interpolation code](http://www.google.com/search?q=linear+interpolation+C%2B%2B) all over the Intarnetz.
- I believe the [Boost libraries](http://boost.org) have support for this. Linear interpolation, not Beziers specifically. Don't quote me on this, however.

Comment: Excellent! I think that code project example will do nicely :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I made an implementation based on this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/11435243/15484522 but for any amount of path points

```
void bezier(int [] arr, int size, int amount) {
  int a[] = new int[size * 2];    
  for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size * 2; j++) a[j] = arr[j];
    for (int j = (size - 1) * 2 - 1; j > 0; j -= 2) 
      for (int k = 0; k <= j; k++) 
        a[k] = a[k] + ((a[k+2] - a[k]) * i) / amount;
    circle(a[0], a[1], 3);  // draw a circle, in Processing
  }
}
```

Where **arr** is array of points {x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3... xn, yn}, **size** is amount of points (twice smaller than array size), and **amount** is number of output points.

For optimal calculations you can use 2^n amount and bit shift:

```
void bezier(int [] arr, int size, int dense) {
  int a[] = new int[size * 2];    
  for (int i = 0; i < (1 << dense); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size * 2; j++) a[j] = arr[j];
    for (int j = (size - 1) * 2 - 1; j > 0; j -= 2) 
      for (int k = 0; k <= j; k++) 
        a[k] = a[k] + (((a[k+2] - a[k]) * i) >> dense);
    circle(a[0], a[1], 3);  // draw a circle, in Processing
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This [implementation on github](https://github.com/Rezonality/mutils/blob/6adc3fa9d160f455092637032cb6fcd6162d0b93/include/mutils/math/math_utils.h#L124) shows how to calculate a simple cubic bezier, with normal and tangent values for values of 't' from 0->1.
It is a direct transposition of the [formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B%C3%A9zier_curves) at wikipedia.