# What C++ library can i use to create and simplify Bezier curves

Tags: c++, bezier, curve, polyline, simplify

In a program I have a polyline that is a set of points. I need to create Bezier curve from it and then simplify it using some threshold value.

Are there any C++ libraries that can be helpful for that task?

Comment: You might want to check [this][1] previews post


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785097/how-do-i-implement-a-bezier-curve-in-c

Comment: Sample implementation: https://github.com/gelldur/common-cpp/blob/master/src/math/Bezier.h

Answer (score 3):

The last time I checked for the computation of Bézier curves in c++ I did not find anything that fits my need, so I wrote this: http://libclaw.sourceforge.net/curves.html.

It may help you to define the curves but there is nothing specifically related to their simplification however.