# Definition of JS SVG function path.getTotalLength()?

Tags: javascript, svg, browser

I would like to know the algorithm used in `path.getTotalLength()` or the definition of the function as defined in any standard specification or the source code of any browser/JS interpreter, since I would like to implement it in C++ for use in an open-source vector graphics software.
Thanks

Comment: Theres no algorithm in the specification. The Mozilla approach is to [flatten the path then calculate the length of the flattened path](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/gfx/2d/Path.cpp). This is C++, check the licence meets your needs.

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785097/how-do-i-implement-a-b%C3%A9zier-curve-in-c ... I suppose you will have to do it yourself and it will probably take weeks of coding and testing

Comment: @RobertLongson I'll have a look into that! Thanks a lot for your answers!